Is an integer like $2$ by just itself an "algebraic" expression?
Basically, my question is what is the standard mathematical definition of algebraic expression.
Most of the places where I looked, it is mentioned that the algebraic expression is the combination of constants and variables with operations of addition and subtraction.
My main question : Is it mandatory for it to have a variable?
For instance, is $2$ an algebraic expression or not?
Can we put the variable as $x^0$  with $2$ to make it $2x^0$ and consider it as algebraic expression?
OR it is not an algebraic expression at all?

there's no standard definition

According to e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression#Algebraic_and_other_mathematical_expressions, yes. I think it's more a question of perspective, i.e., how are you using the number? E.g., you could say that an algebraic equation is an equation with an algebraic expression on either side, for example $x^2+x = 2$. Here it make sense to call $2$ an algebraic expression. But I wouldn't worry too much about any of this. It's not a widely used formal/precise term.

We can identify $2$ the natural number with $2$ the integer, with $2$ the real number, with $2$ the polynomial, and so on. These are all, sort of, different, but we can identify them. But regardless, “algebraic expression” has no standardized meaning.

It is a matter of definition but per your example, $2=2x^0$ is indeed considered an "algebraic expression", a monomial to be precise under most definitions I know of, including the ones taught under the current standard curricula of the country I reside in both in school and university. So, yes, it is.

Does it really matter, Bijay, whether $2$ is an algebraic expression? Is there any situation in which it makes a difference?

It’s perfectly reasonable to call $2$ an expression. And besides $2x^0$, there are plenty of other expressions that equal it. Like $\frac{7x-5x}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$.

Wikipedia says that constants are algebraic expressions.

There is no "commonly agreed" terminology here.
The question is intimately connected to the question "Why does it matter ?" which will dictate the answer.
DISCUSSION :
(1) "Why does it matter ?" : We want closure of the relevant operators.
Well , when we have algebraic expressions like $A_1(x)=x^2+2x+3$ , $A_2(x)=x^2+5x+6$ , $A_3(x)=2x^2+7x+6$ , $A_4(x)=2x^8+8x+86$ , then we want that $A_1+A_2$ , $A_1-8A_2$ , $A_1+A_2+A_3$ , $A_1-A_2+A_3-A_4$ are all algebraic expressions.
Then we can easily see that $A_1-A_1=0$ , $A_1+A_2-A_3=3$ , $A_1-A_2=-3$ , $A_1-A_2+A_3-A_4-A_1+A_2-A_3+A_4=0$ are also algebraic expressions.
Hence Integers must be algebraic expressions.
(2) "Why does it matter ?" : We want the expression to vary when the variable varies.
Well , when we have algebraic expressions like $A_1(x)=x^2+2x+3$ , then it will vary when $x$ varies.
Here $7$ , $-7$ , $0$ , $0.0$ , $7x^0$ , $0y$ , $0.0z$ , $0w^0$ will not vary.
In that Case , Integers must not be algebraic expressions.
(3) "Why does it matter ?" : We want want to have the variable "visible" in the expression.
Well , then we have algebraic expressions like $A_1(x)=x^2+2x+3$ involving $x$ , $A_2(y)=y^2+5y+6$ involving $y$ , $A_3(z)=2z^2+7z+6$ involving $z$ , $A_4(w)=2w^8+8w+86$ involving $w$ , then we want that $7$ , $-7$ , $0$ , $0.0$ are not algebraic expressions , since the variable is not "visible".
Strangely , $7x^0$ , $-7y^0$ , $0z$ , $0.0w$ are algebraic expressions here , due to the "visibility" of the variables.
[[ When needed , the "visibility" concept can be formalized using languages & grammars ]]
(4) "Why does it matter ?" : We want to make the "hierarchy" of expressions.
Something similar to : $1$ is inside Natural numbers which are inside Integers which are inside algebraic numbers which are inside computable numbers which are inside real numbers which are inside complex numbers ....
Then our "hierarchy" will decide whether Integers are algebraic expressions or not.
SUMMARY :
There is no "commonly agreed" terminology here.
The answer depend on the context where the question arises.

I'd quibble that 2) is a silly objective.  Why would we require variability corresponding to variable variance?  What tenet would expect that?  Wouldn't that apply to functions.  Are constant functions not allowed.  Also if the variable $x$ changing require changes in the expression what if $x\ne x'$ but the expression is the same for both.  Would $x^2-5x+8$ not be an expression because it doesn't vary as $x$ changes from $x=2$ to $x=3$?

But I do like this answer and I think it gets to the heart of the issue.

It was quite hard to cook up 4 contexts with 4 mutually exclusive answers. Naturally some of them will turn out fictitious at certain levels. My Preference was (1) where Integers are indeed algebraic expressions. Thank you , @fleablood , for your support.

Just clarifying , the variability is not at few Points , it is across the Domain/range , where few Points can/will have same value. Not that I support it : Maybe the context is differentiating between "constants" & "basic variables" & "extended variables which are expressions" !

My preference is also for 1).  I suppose a fifth option would be "Why does it matter:  We care about context.  I wouldn't bring a frying pan to a wood working class so I'm not going to bring an algebraic expression to a discrete mathematics course"  $2$ is an algebraic express when we are doing algebra.  $2$ is not an algebraic expression when we are doing number theory (nor when we are singing the Sesame Street counting song).

I teach that an algebraic expression needs to have a variable, since algebra involves dealing with unknown quantities.  2 would therefore just be a numerical expression or a term.  I'd just use "term", since a term is either a number, a variable, or a product of numbers and/or variables.

Answering your question with another question:
Suppose that you're a software developer implementing a computer algebra system (CAS).  And I literally mean “algebra”: No logarithms, trig functions, integrals, or anything else that can't be expressed by a finite number of $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, or nth root operations.
If the user entered y = 2 (where = means assignment, not equality comparison), would you show a message like “ERROR: 2 is not an algebraic expression” and urge the user to replace it with something like x + 2 - x that contains a variable that ends up not mattering?  Or would you just accept it and set y to the constant value 2?
If the latter, then it's reasonable to call 2 by itself an algebraic expression.

Plus, Wikipedia says that constants are algebraic expressions.
